# concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor does not work on Slurm

Tags: slurm

I run a program on a mac os system with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. it performs well and I found there were 8 processes because my CPU has 8 cores. However, when I run it on slurm it is time-wasting. my script is as following. there are 18 tasks set because I want to create processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=18
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --mem=8g
#SBATCH --tmp=5g
#SBATCH -t 80:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=meng0167@umn.edu
#SBATCH -p amdsmall
#SBATCH -e %j.err
#SBATCH -o %j.out

cd $SLURM SUBMIT DIR

module load python3
module load pyrosetta
python3 test_process.py
```

**Please help me, I have been stuck in it for 1 week.**